# TypeScript Replace Between Letters

Tags: typescript, string, methods, replace, cocoscreator

I have a problem with the "replace" method. It doesn't work correctly. I'm working with the game engine Cocos Creator v.3.8.1.
I need to place spaces in a string between letters, and 3 spaces between words.

I use the following code for this:

```
let testStr : string = "test string";
testStr = testStr.toUpperCase().replace(' ','#').split('').join(' ').replace('#',' ');
console.log(testStr);
```

But for some reason there is only 1 symbol between words.

`Output: T E S T S T R I N G`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the OP is replacing spaces with `#` because after putting in spaces between every character she needs to know where the original spaces were (so she can make a triple space there). And this is then as simple as replacing the `#` with a space, because then there's 3 spaces (left and right to the `#` there are already 2).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I know this method will work once. Have you read what I want to do? I want there to be ONE space between LETTERS and THREE spaces between WORDS.

Comment: The code is actually correct, if you would log out `testStr` instead of `test`, see the [TypeScript Playground where I pasted it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBGIM5gymAThAXBOSCWA7A5hALwQBE0cGyueJA3AFDkLJFSzNIB0YA9gKoAHASCQBhAIYwQACgCUnJCAHBxAYxkByCBoA0GgMQb5MZVjDSNRzgCseuC9vmLlazYb2OGqnjhg9QnMA8eNJMiEiytEA) (and logged the right variable). Click "Run" there.

Comment: @lchristmann Yes. It works. But for some reason this doesn't work in Cocos Creator :(

Comment: Have you tried using regex patterns for the replacements? From the specification of the replace method I don't see why the code works xD It's weird, that it just does. :D So does `.replace(/\s/g, '#').split('').join(' ').replace(/#/g, ' ');` work? [\s is the JS regex for whitespace characters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-regexp-s-metacharacter/).

Comment: @lchristmann This also doesn't work. :D Probably the problem is directly related to the game engine. :(

Comment: Yeah, most likely. The code even works in plain JavaScript, I [tested it on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mz9461eL/11/). What you can do still, if you want to make this work, is break it up in really small steps. Then log every tiny step of the way with `console.log` until you find the exact method call that doesn't do what it's supposed to. Good old "Divide and conquer" strategy.

Comment: @lchristmann The problem turned out to be the last "replace" method, which replaces the "#" symbol with a space. For some reason this method removes adjacent spaces. =/

Comment: Ohhhh okay. Good job figuring that out! Then you'll probably replace the `#` with 3 spaces instead of one?

Comment: @lchristmann I still haven't solved my problem. :D I found the cause of my problem, but I still can't understand how it works in Сocos Creator. If I use " replace("#", " ") " then I get the string "T E S T S T R I N G", with one space between the words.
But if I use " replace("#", "123") ", then I get what I expect: "T E S T 123 S T R I N G". Word-Space-123-Space-Word. Someone is stealing my spaces :)

Comment: Haha. :D This should be illegal! (This surely does not sound ES6/ECMAScript 2015 compliant) Although [Cocos Creator claims in its docs to be ES2015 when using TypeScript per default](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/manual/en/scripting/language-support.html)

Comment: Now an easy solution you could try still is using different methods. E.g. a `for` loop and string concatenation. Checkout [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b28d43s/12/). It splits the string into words and uses a for-loop process each word (inserting spaces between letters + add 3 trailing spaces). Like this we entirely avoid using the `replace` method.